# IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, excel, numpy, csv, indexing

I'm trying to graph `G` versus `l1`. The data is in the file that I loaded from an excel file. The excel file is 14x250 so there are 14 arguments, each with 250 data points.

So here is the code in question:

```py
# format for CSV file:
header = ['l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'l4', 'l5', 'EI', 'S', 'P_right', 'P1_0', 
          'P3_0', 'w_left', 'w_right', 'G_left', 'G_right']

def loadfile(filename, skip=None):
    skip = set(skip or [])
    with open(filename) as f:
        cr = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        return np.array(row for i,row in enumerate(cr) if i not in skip)

outputs_l1 = [loadfile('{}.csv'.format(p)) for p in p3_arr]
col = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(header)}

for data in outputs_l1:
    xs  = data[:, col["l1"     ]]
    gl = data[:, col["G_left" ]] * 1000.0    # column 12
    gr = data[:, col["G_right"]] * 1000.0    # column 13
```

After running the entire program, I receive the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Work/Python Stuff/New Stuff from Brenday 8 26 2014/CD_ssa_plot(2).py", line 115, in <module>
    xs  = data[:, col["l1"     ]]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

and before I ran into that problem, I had another involving the line a few below the one the above error message refers to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "FILE", line 119, in <module> 
gl = data[:, col["G_left" ]] * 1000.0 # column 12 
IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 12
```

Comment: arrays are zero based,  there is no index 12 in a 12 element array

Comment: Have you tried putting `print data` after `for data,color in zip(outputs_l1, colors):` to see what each row of data looks like?  It seems like it may not be formatted in the way you expect it to be (your belief is that it's going to be an array of 14 elements, right?  looks like there are instances where there are only 12 elements)

Comment: when I type 'print data' or 'print outputs_l1' it says that those are invalid syntax.  and there are 14 arguments so the last two are going to be #12 and #13, which is what I'm calling on for the graph.  And where do you see any instances where there are only 12?  That was my problem before and I thought I fixed that but I may have missed something

Comment: are you using Python 3.x?  in which case it should be `print(data)` instead.  `IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 12` is explicit that there's a data row that contains only 12 elements somewhere.

Answer (score 83):

I think the problem is given in the error message, although it is not very easy to spot:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
xs  = data[:, col["l1"     ]]
```

'Too many indices' means you've given too many index values.  You've given 2 values as you're expecting data to be a 2D array.  Numpy is complaining because `data` is not 2D (it's either 1D or None).

This is a bit of a guess - I wonder if one of the filenames you pass to loadfile() points to an empty file, or a badly formatted one?  If so, you might get an array returned that is either 1D, or even empty (`np.array(None)` does not throw an `Error`, so you would never know...).  If you want to guard against this failure, you can insert some error checking into your `loadfile` function.

I highly recommend in your `for` loop inserting:

```
print(data)
```

This will work in Python 2.x or 3.x and might reveal the source of the issue.  You might well find it is only one value of your `outputs_l1` list (i.e. one file) that is giving the issue.

Answer (score 12):

The message that you are getting is not for the default Exception of Python:

For a fresh python list, [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#IndexError) is thrown only on index not being in range (even [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#IndexError) say so).

```
>>> l = []
>>> l[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If we try passing multiple items to list, or some other value, we get the `TypeError`:

```
>>> l[1, 2]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

>>> l[float('NaN')]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

However, here, you seem to be using [`matplotlib` that internally uses `numpy`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/search?q=numpy&unscoped_q=numpy) for handling arrays. On digging deeper through the [codebase for `numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/22fe5427be1f3a0b186d01a09ff46092a42a0aa1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L161), we see:

```
static NPY_INLINE npy_intp
unpack_tuple(PyTupleObject *index, PyObject **result, npy_intp result_n)
{
    npy_intp n, i;
    n = PyTuple_GET_SIZE(index);
    if (n > result_n) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError,
                        "too many indices for array");
        return -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result[i] = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(index, i);
        Py_INCREF(result[i]);
    }
    return n;
}
```

where, the unpack method will throw an error if it the size of the index is greater than that of the results.

So, Unlike Python which raises a `TypeError` on incorrect Indexes, Numpy raises the `IndexError` because it supports multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is 9 years too late but the error is caused by the fact that the OP creates the array using a generator expression in the `loadfile` definition, which returns a 0-dimension ndarray.

```py
np.array(row for i,row in enumerate(cr) if i not in skip)    # <--- culprit

np.array([row for i,row in enumerate(cr) if i not in skip])  # <--- fix
#        ^                                               ^   # <--- create array from list
```

---

In general, `IndexError: too many indices for array` is saying that you tried to index a dimension that isn't there, e.g. try to index columns in a 1D ndarray, try to index 3rd dimension in a 2D ndarray etc.

```py
# 1D ndarray: arr.ndim==1
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2])
arr[0]         # <--- OK
arr[:, 0]      # <--- IndexError: too many indices for array


# 2D ndarray: ary.ndim==2
ary = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
])

ary[0]         # <--- OK
ary[:, 0]      # <--- OK
ary[:, :, 0]   # <--- IndexError: too many indices for array
```

---

On the other hand, `IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 12` is saying that while the dimensions are OK, you tried to index outside the bounds of the ndarray. Since ndarrays are 0-indexed, to index the last column, we should either use `-1` or `arr.shape[1]-1`.

```py
# 1D ndarray of length 3
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2])
arr[2]      # <--- OK
arr[3]      # <--- IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3


# 2x2 ndarray
ary = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
])

ary[:, 1]   # <--- OK
ary[:, -1]  # <--- OK
ary[:, 2]   # <--- IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2
```

Answer (score -2):

Before transforming the data into a *list*, I transformed the data into a  list

`data = list(data) data = np.array(data)`