# Python "Too many indices for array"

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading a file in python using pandas and then saving it in a numpy array. 
The file has the dimension of 11303402 rows x 10 columns. 
I need to split the data for cross validation and for that I sliced the data into 11303402 rows x 9 columns of examples and 1 array of 11303402 rows x 1 col of labels.
The following is the code:

```
tdata=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
tdata.columns='Arrival_Time','Creation_Time','x','y','z','User','Model','Device','sensor','gt']

User_Data = np.array(tdata)
features = User_Data[:,0:9]
labels = User_Data[:,9:10]
```

The error comes in the following code:

```
classes=np.unique(labels)
idx=labels==classes[0]
Yt=labels[idx]
Xt=features[idx,:]
```

On the line:

```
Xt=features[idx,:]
```

it says 'too many indices for array'

The shapes of all 3 data sets are:

```
print np.shape(tdata) = (11303402, 10)
print np.shape(features) = (11303402, 9)
print np.shape(labels) = (11303402, 1)
```

If anyone knows the problem, please help.

Comment: What is `c`?  A complete, standalone, runnable program with self-generated random (or zero) input data would help.

Comment: Try removing the semicolon so that you have `Xt=features[idx:]`.

Comment: And what is the shape of `idx`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sorry i updated the code. It just means the first class in classes and shape of `idx` is `(11303402,1)`
@WoozyCoder Nopes, didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndexError: too many indices for array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036812/indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is `idx` has shape `(11303402,1)` because the logical comparison returns an array of the same shape as `labels`.  These two dimensions use all of the indexes in `features`. The quick work around is

```
Xt=features[idx[:,0],:]
```