# Python: IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, indexing

The following piece of code is throwing an error when I run it:

```
model_ridge = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=False, tol=0.0001, C=9081)
model_randomforest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 200)
pred_ridge = []
pred_randomforest = []
new_Y = []
for i in range(10):
    indxs = np.arange(i, X.shape[0], 10)
    indxs_to_fit = list(set(range(X.shape[0])) - set(np.arange(i, X.shape[0], 10)))
    pred_ridge = pred_ridge + list(model_ridge.fit(X[indxs_to_fit,:1], y[indxs_to_fit,:1]).predict_proba(X[indxs,:1])[:,1])
    pred_randomforest = pred_randomforest + list(model_randomforest.fit(X[indxs_to_fit,:], y[indxs_to_fit,:]).predict_proba(X[indxs,:])[:,1])
    new_Y = new_Y + list(y[indxs,:])
```

This is the error:

```
line 159, in <module>
pred_ridge = pred_ridge + list(model_ridge.fit(X[indxs_to_fit,:1], y[indxs_to_fit,:1]).predict_proba(X[indxs,:1])[:,1])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I can't understand what's going on, could you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be slicing your X variable wrong.. what are you trying to do here: X[indxs_to_fit,:1] ?

Comment: and also: [:,1]..should this be [:1] ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndexError: too many indices for array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036812/indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array)

Comment: Thank You for reply
I'm trying to fit the model according to the given training data: 
Input parameters:

1) X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training vector, where n_samples in the number of samples and
            n_features is the number of features.

2) y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)
            Target vector relative to X.

3) sample_weight : array-like, shape (n_samples,) optional
            Array of weights that are assigned to individual samples.
            If not provided, then each sample is given unit weight.

Comment: can't enter new row, sorry for this(

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with [:,1] ?

Comment: take every first row in list

Comment: but problem is not in this thing, even if i delete this element, same issue oocures

Comment: You get the first result from a list using [0] ?

Comment: using :1, or i'm wrong?

Comment: you can slice using [:1] yes. there should be no comma

Comment: what do you mean? "migrating to chat"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted

Comment: The same applies to the other X[] calls too - remove your commas

Comment: i.e X[indxs_to_fit,:]

Comment: same error
Python seems difficult for me)

Comment: And i was using [:,1] right
It take second element of each array element [[1,[2,3]], [4,[5,6]], ... [n1,[n2,n3]]]
so it'll be [ 1 => 3, 4 => 6 , ... , n1 => n3]