# IndexError: too many indices for array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an input training dataset of dimension(1500, 5)and an output training dataset for(1499, 1). Please suggest what I can do to eliminate the error.

```
Error: Y = dataframe1[:,0]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Code:

```
dataframe = np.genfromtxt('DataInput.csv', delimiter=",")
#pandas.read_csv("DataInput.csv", delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
#dataset = dataframe.values

dataframe1 = np.genfromtxt("OptimizedSpeed.csv", delimiter=",")
#dataset1 = dataframe1.values

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables

X = dataframe[:,0:4]
**Y = dataframe1[:,0]** <-- this line shows the error
```

Comment: Just check whether your dataframe1 is loading properly or not

Comment: use `Y = dataframe1[:]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndexError: too many indices for array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036812/indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array)

Comment: You are using `numpy`, right? Add tag to your question. Provide example portions of you `csv`-files.

Comment: Added the numpy tag.