# problem in indices of y for the command train_test_split (problem with setting stratify)

Tags: python, arrays, testing, shapes, training-data

In order to divide to train test data :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y.iloc[:,1], test_size=0.3,random_state=seed, stratify=y)
```

but when I run I saw this error:(I have written the size of x and y)

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ...
>    , in <module>
>    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y.iloc[:,1], test_size=0.3,random_state=seed, stratify=y)
>     AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'
> ```

---

**EDIT**:
The shapes are:

```
Shape(X)= (284807, 28)
Shape(y)= (284807,)
```

Then I used:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y[:,1], test_size=0.3,random_state=seed, stratify=y)
```

But I saw:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

How to solve this problem?

Comment: iloc attribute is available on pandas series and dataframe objects it is not the attribute of numpy ndarray. Use indexing and slicing to access elements of ndarray

Comment: naveen tamanam how to solve it?

Comment: say it clearly.would you please say it clearly?

Comment: what's the output of `y.shape` and `X.shape` ?

Comment: Shape(X)= (284807, 28)
Shape(y)= (284807,)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, try replacing `y.iloc[:,1]` by `y`:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, 
                                                    y, 
                                                    test_size=0.3,
                                                    random_state=seed)
```

**Edit:**
As the documentation suggests, the size of the stratify parameters must be **`2 * len(arrays)`**  where array is `X` or `y`.

Comment: Check the shape of `y` with `print(y.shape)`. The new error message mean `y` is a one dimensional vector and you're trying to select 2 dimensions. For more explanations, have a look at [IndexError: too many indices for array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036812/indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array)

Comment: I have written the size of y in question: Shape(X)= (284807, 28) Shape(y)= (284807,) the reason I used [:,1] is to change it but it does not work!

Comment: What's about the updated answer ?

Comment: \site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 1636, in _iter_indices
    raise ValueError("The least populated class in y has only 1"
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.

Comment: The `stratify` options is raising this error. As the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) suggests, the size of the `stratify` parameters must be `2 * len(arrays)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205378/discussion-between-alexandre-b-and-user10296606).

Answer (score -1):

[iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) is method of pandas DataFrame and Series Objects

To access elements you may use ndarray with indexing and slicing notation or convert ndarray to pandas data frame as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(nda)
y = df.iloc[:,1].to_numpy() #convert selected series from DataFrame to ndarray
```

DataFrames offer great flexibility in working with data.  Since train_test_split takes arrays as arguments DataFrame can be converted to ndarray using [DataFrame.to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy)

Comment: Please see above comments